Missing Panel on Android Studio (Horizontally in Parent)
Going through an Android course. I am not sure, if I missed an extension, but I cannot access the panel below.
In particular I am looking to access the button "Horizontally in Parent".
Would you know how to display it on the panel?
My current panel

Desired panel


In the component tree right click on your root layout -> Convert to ConstraintLayout
